# Что означают 1 и -1 в следующей функции?

Tags: javascript

```js
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  }
}


var numArr = [1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 11, 54, 88];

numArr.sort(compareNumeric);

document.write(numArr);
```

Comment: Хм. Любопытно, как оно поведёт себя, если в компаратор попадут равные элементы.

Comment: числовые элементы смешались в кучу малу..... а вообще, я так и не понял, какая связь между 1, -1  и  элементами  в массиве... Допустим 1 5. Хорошо, == -4. Что дальше происходит?

Comment: Для этого вам надо изучить какой-нибудь алгоритм сортировки в деталях. Самые простые: сортировка пузырьком и сортировка вставками. Такой компаратор можно применить в почти любом (кроме чего-нибудь экзотического, вроде поразрядной или подсчётной).